# When printing an array in C# I get the values all bunched up together

Tags: c#

For the following code in C# my array outputs as 
"12152288" instead of spaces in between them. What can I do to fix this?
[Here is the Output error I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqBrL.png) And here is the code.

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] numbers = {12, 15, 22, 88};
    int x;
    double average;
    double total = 0;
    Console.Write("\nThe numbers are...");
    for(x = 0; x < numbers.Length; ++x)
        Write("{0}", numbers[x]);
    Console.WriteLine();      
    for(x = 0; x < numbers.Length; ++x)
    {
        total = total + numbers[x];
    }   
    average = total / numbers.Length;
    Console.Write("The average is {0}", average);
}
```

Comment: You are not telling it to print a space, comma or anything else in `Write("{0}", numbers[x]);`

Comment: ... add a space to your output?

Comment: well, you don't write spaces anywhere... `Write("\nThe numbers are... ");` and `Write("{0} ", numbers[x]);` (note the extra white space).

Comment: Could use `String.Join(" ", numbers.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray())` to join the numbers in advance.

Comment: Yes I know I need to add a space somewhere but I'm not sure on how to do it to achieve "12 15 22 88".

Comment: So experiment a bit...

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
Write("{0}", numbers[x]);
```

To this:

```
Console.Write("{0} ", numbers[x]);
```

Comment: Not sure why you bother posting an answer to such a low quality question... if that's the way you got to 287k rep, this system is seriously broken...

Comment: @Nyerguds It only took a moment to do. Lot's of people start out asking low quality questions, and only stick around to learn how to ask better ones if they have a more positive experience early. I find an _edit_ to improve the question and a short answer (if the OP didn't put effort into asking a question, there's no need to put much effort into the answer) are often better responses then a passive-aggressive comment.